# Logistic Regression with Gradient Descent on large data

Tags: logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I have a training set with about 300000 examples and about 50-60 features and also it's a multiclass with about 7 classes. I have my logistic regression function that finds out the convergence of the parameters using gradient descent. My gradient descent algorithm, finds the parameters in matrix form as it's faster in matrix form than doing separately and linearly in loops.
Ex : 
Matrix(P) <- Matrix(P) - LearningRate( T(Matrix(X)) * ( Matrix(h(X)) -Matrix(Y) ) )

For small training data, it's quite fast and gives correct values with maximum iterations to be around 1000000, but with that much training data, it's extremely slow, that with around 500 iterations it takes 18 minutes, but with that much iterations in gradient descent, the cost is still high and it does not predict the class correctly.

I know, I should implement maybe feature selection, or feature scaling and I can't use the packages provided. Language used is R. How do I go about implementing feature selection or scaling without using any library packages.

Answer (score 0):

According to [link](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#z-score-standardization-or-min-max-scaling), you can use either Z-score normalization or min-max scaling method. Both methods scale the data to [0,1] range. [Z-score normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) is calculated as 
[image]

[Min-max scaling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) is calculated as:

[image]